# Controller and API DTO Architecture and class organization in .net core with microservices

Tags: rest, class-design, web-api, asp.net-core, controller

We are developing a system with coarse microservice architecture. We have an API that uses controllers and back-end logic with Entity-Framework repository, and several types of clients that use this API, all in dotnet, therefore, typesafe.

We need to use some sort of data transfer objects for communication between the API and the clients. Clients are using REST calls. However, our controllers need to hide some properties of the entities for:

- different clients (e.g. metadata of entity for web clients and no metadata for mobile clients)
- different controller actions (e.g. `/Users/` returns a list of `User` DTOs having only name and surname, whereas `/Users/{id}` returns user details. )
- different REST methods (e.g. a `Post` requests would not have timestamps as it is created server-side)

My question is: what would be a good design for reusability? Is the best practice creating new classes for all requests/responses? We wouldn't want to use dynamic objects. I thought of Builder pattern, but I am not sure if that fits here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is that you use a single derived class containing all properties in common for a given entity.  For example a `User` class with first name, last name, and last logged in timestamp.

To represent data coming from mobile device, you have a derived version of `User` called `MobileUser` extending the existing properties with your meta information pertaining to a mobile user such as mobile device type, resolution, etc.

Everywhere in your web application where you only need `User`, you use only `User`.  In the parts of your program where you need to differentiate, you implement that in `User`.  For example, to persist `User` instance to the database, you'd call its `User.save()` method.  `User.save()` would be responsible for saving all properties common to all derived classes and `MobileUser.save()` would be responsible for saving the properties specific to `MobileUser`.  Logic would dictate that you would use separate tables in your database as well, though you're free to do whatever you deem is best.

Of course, don't fill these methods with the logic of calling the sql query and such.  Rely on another class to perform generic persistence operations passing the data that you wish to persist to the method.  You could use a `UserDAO` class to save `User` instances and `MobileUserDAO` to save `MobileUser` instances.  It doesn't matter.  The crucial thing is that where the separation in your program is required, you do so without having to figure out its type.

For what concerns returning the data, a [facade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) pattern would probably suit you well enough here.  The idea is that you separate the actual entity data from where and how it is used.  You could use a facade wrapping an entity to make available only the properties you wish to return keeping private properties hidden away in the part of your program that doesn't use it.

Comment: Thank you, we have implemented in a similar fashion, though found out that this creates too many classes to manage. This is why I am investigating a reuse-friendly means. But it seems like there is no other way if we would like to use a type-safe interface.

Comment: @YamaçKurtuluş Well if each type has its own properties, then there is no problem whatsoever having the extra classes as it is justified.  You can reuse classes where viable too (an iphone user may still fall under MobileUser for instance).  The complexity is only as deep as you want it to be,  ultimately.